# SQL SSAS Cube Deploy Error:

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, cube, bids, sql-server-2012-datatools

I am trying to deploy a cube I created in SQL Server Data Tool using AdventureWorksDW2008R2,   I used windows authentication login the database engine with all permissions granted to it.   and yet I still get these arrors in the picture below when deploying the cube. Anyone Can point out which part is wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I know which option in the Data Source designer did you choose before deployment?

Note that based on the page below, even if your account has access to the database, you cannot use ImpersonateCurrentUser option.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189027.aspx

Have you tried using the "Use a specific username and password" and entering the login details?

Comment: the data source I have tried each option ,  specific login with pw,   service account,   current user, inherit.    I just want to tell you the problem somehow got fixed but I don't understand why ,  the changes I made is  I logout the database engine instance, and login the Analysis Service instance,  also I add a new login  with login name 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService',  but I dont think the new login helped ,  instead of it might has something to do with the analysis service and  I used inherit option and it worked.

Comment: Agree that it could work that way as well. Just thought you might want to use a different account other than the service account to connect to the data source. Anyway, good to hear it works now :)